# why the parameter list is ok, but "$*" will be wrong?

Tags: bash, shell

I know "$*" can not generate the parameters array,it will only return a parameters string.but today I use a parameter named list and let list equal "$*", then I use "for" loop structure, but the result is right. why?

```
#!/bin/bash
# testing $* and "$*"
list="$*"
for i in $list
do
    echo $i >> file$i
done
```

For instance:
./test 1 2 3 4
Then my directory will have file1 file2 file3 and file4, It turns out the answer is right!

Comment: It means that list is still a parameters array?

Comment: No it is not an array. Use `"$@"` for that

Comment: @ZhangTao, try this test: `./test "1 2 3" "4 5 6"` -- how many output files do you think you'll get?